# Oracle PL/SQL Variable in HAVING clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm having some troubles with putting a variable in a HAVING clause, the problem is that I need COUNT(*) to be greater than the variable.

I'm using ORACLE Database XE 11.2

```
DECLARE


  cnt1 NUMBER;
  cnt2 NUMBER;
  res NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO cnt1
    FROM BESTELLING;

  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO cnt2
    FROM ARTIKEL;

  res := cnt1 / cnt2;
END;
/

SELECT A.Naam, COUNT(*) AS HOEVEEL_VERKOCHT
FROM Artikel A, Winkelwagen W
WHERE A.Artikel_ID = W.Artikel_ID
AND W.Datum_Besteld IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A.Naam
HAVING COUNT(*) > ?res?
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: But your SQL query is *outside* the PL/SQL block.  Obviously it won't be able to access any of the variables defined *inside* the PL/SQL block.

Comment: How would you do it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place queries from PL/SQL directly in your main query, as subqueries:

```
.......
HAVING COUNT(*) > 
   (  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BESTELLING )   /
   (  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ARTIKEL )
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

such  way wont work ?

```
DECLARE


  cnt1 NUMBER;
  cnt2 NUMBER;
  result NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO cnt1
    FROM BESTELLING;

  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO cnt2
    FROM ARTIKEL;

  result := cnt1 / cnt2;
SELECT A.Naam, res, COUNT(*) AS HOEVEEL_VERKOCHT
FROM Artikel A, Winkelwagen W
WHERE A.Artikel_ID = W.Artikel_ID
AND W.Datum_Besteld IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A.Naam, res
HAVING COUNT(*) > result
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;

END;
/
```

I change variable res to result , because it seems you have column called res

Comment: No I'm getting this error when I'm doing this: 

PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Comment: And thank you for pointing out that I had res still in my SELECT, that was an accident. I updated the code.

Comment: we can add into a variable but do you want to dislpay out or you want to insert into a table ?

Comment: your welcome , useally when your work with plsql block they job to update table or procedures. so the value you get it what do you want to do ?